# how to prevent entering interactive elements by press tab？

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

While pressing tab on the page，
when tab on one interactive element(user defined), it automatically enter into it, and the tab navigating on the internal subelemnet of the interactive element

how to prevent this?

I hope we can use enter/esc to get in/out this interactive element, not directly get into it while tab on it.

moer details:
I try to clear my question: Suppose my page have two elements like one button and one excel render view, I can use tab to focus on both of them, however, the view of excel is an interactive element, which means when I tab on the view of excel, the following tab will move in the cells of the excel I hope I can only tab between the button and the view of the excel, only if I use the enter key on the view of the excel, then let it tab between cells of the excel, and hopefully I can use ESC key to leave out from the view the excel

Comment: Have you considering looking at onkeydown and preventing the default the default for this key? Its more work, but you can control how elements are tabbed this way... Also see @Jack Bendtsen's comment as it might be what you are looking for (I'm not exactly sure what you are saying for sure).

Comment: You are asking this question like this would be a general issue. You are describing a focus trap, which does not occur in native web elements. What is the component that poses your issue? Where does it come from, how is it integrated, and what level of control do you have on it? What is its API?
ARIA keyboard navigation patterns mainly use arrow keys to navigate within a component, which totally would make sense for your Excel component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user component allows exiting by means of tab at the end of the table, you are not failing [WCAG 2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?showtechniques=212#no-keyboard-trap).

That being said, and as you already have realised, this is not a great user experience.

If you don’t have any control on that component, this is something you could try:

- Make the wrapper of the component focussable by means of `tabindex="0"`
- Give it an accessible name by means of `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`
- Give it an active/inactive status, which controls whether tab will navigate inside of it, or to the next component
- Listen to <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> to toggle this status
- Listen to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the [`focusin` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event), to avoid navigation inside when it’s not active (you might skip listening on Tab, as the result would be another focusin)
- Don’t forget to explain to the user (including screen reader users) how to navigate the thing

```js
c = document.getElementById('component');
next = document.getElementById('next-tabstop');

c.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch (e.code) {
    case "Tab":
      // Tab to the next component if not active
      if (c.dataset.active !== "true") {
        next.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      break;

    case "Escape":
      // Exit tab of the table
      c.dataset.active="false";
      c.focus();
      break;

    case "Enter":
      // Tab into the table
      c.dataset.active="true";
      c.querySelector("[tabindex='0']").focus();
      break;
  }
});

// Avoid backwards navigation directly onto the last focusable descendend
c.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
  if (c.dataset.active !== "true") {
    c.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

:focus {
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p><button>A humble button</button></p>

<h2 id="component-title">Table</h2>
<p id="component-desc">Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate into the table, <kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit the table</p>

<div tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="component-title" aria-describedby="component-desc" id="component" data-active="false">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th tabindex="0"></th>
        <th tabindex="0">A</th>
        <th tabindex="0">B</th>
        <th tabindex="0">C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th tabindex="0">1</th>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th tabindex="0">2</th>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th tabindex="0">3</th>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
        <td tabindex="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p><button id="next-tabstop">Let’s move on</button></p>
```

To have an accessible page, the table component needs to be accessible, as well, and there are more guidelines to follow.

One would expect to navigate grids by means of arrow keys, and also Home and End should work with certain modifiers. See, for example, [ARIA Practice of Keyboard Navigation for Data Grids](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dataGrid)

If inside these cells there are widgets again, it’s going to get complicated, because then keyboard control of the table itself becomes difficult. You can refer to the [ARIA Grid Widget Role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#grid).

Comment: I’m still wondering about the right role of that wrapper, and [`composite`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#composite) comes into mind. It’s a `widget`, though, which would indicate that more advanced app navigation was possible, which is not the case for the mentioned table, which doesn’t even allow arrow key navigation.

Comment: great， I sloved it by adding aria-hidden attribute

Comment: Hm. How exactly did you apply aria hidden? Because it hides en element entirely from screen readers, potentially confusing sr users.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I'd recommend checking out the [tabindex HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), and possibly [accesskey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) as well. I'd make this a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.